# entering values into an array in react from given 2d array

Tags: reactjs

I want to enter the first value from every array inside a 2d array, I get the 2d array from the server and my intentions are to use it in one of the client pages (as chart data).

Here is the relevant code:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitcoin")
      .then((res) => res.json()) 
      .then((data) => setData(data.message))
      .then((dates) => {
        //code right here
      })
  }, []);
```

Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: do you mean you get an array from the backend which contains multiple arrays and you want to get the first value of every array inside your array (the one you got from the backend ?)

Comment: exactly, thanks<3

Comment: add `useState` code to help implementing it in your `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

It's too easy :

```
const twoDArray = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["aa", "bb", "cc"],
    ["AA", "BB", "CC"] ]

const firstElements = twoDArray.map(item => item[0]);

console.log(firstElements);

// answer: [ 'a', 'A', 'aa', 'AA' ]
```

Let me know if it is what you exactly need.

Update :

That was the main idea you need and you can implement like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitcoin")
      .then(res => res.json()) 
      .then(jsonData => {

           // I assume that jsonData is your 2D array

           const twoDimensionArr = jsonData ;
           setData(twoDimensionArr);               
           const firstElementsArr = twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[0]);    
           console.log(firstElementsArr);
      })
       
  }, []);
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I meant, as you can see I'm getting the data with a fetch request, I am not sure how am I getting only the first value of every array inside the array, and also as an array. the implementation with the fetch request is important to me

Comment: That was the main idea you need.

Comment: I edit my main answer so check it. I hope it helps you

Comment: Also, as a tip, I highly recommend you install and use Axios library for fetching data. It is more useful than fetch command.

Answer (score 0):

**first method**  :
you can use `for...of`  like this :

```
    const Arr  = [ 
    [ 1,2,3,4], 
    ['one',  'two' , 'three'], 
    ['un' ,'deux', 'trois' ], 
    
]

const ArrOfFirstValues = []
for(key of Arr){
   ArrOfFirstValues.push(key[0])
}

console.log(ArrOfFirstValues)
```

the output is  :   `[ 1, 'one', 'un' ]`

**Second method**  :

you can use `.map` to iterate it  :

```
const Arr  = [ 
    [ 1,2,3,4], 
    ['one',  'two' , 'three'], 
    ['un' ,'deux', 'trois' ], 
    
]
console.log(Arr )

const ArrOfFirstValues  =  Arr.map(arr => arr[0])

console.log(ArrOfFirstValues)
```

the output will be :

```
[ 1, 'one', 'un' ]
```

Comment: first off, thank you for your comment <3 but please note that I'm trying to find an implementation within the useEffect method, in other words, I get the array from the server.

Comment: instead of `//code right here` please write `console.log(dates)` and let us know what `dates` is